# How do I achieve a PPPoE connection over wifi?

Tags: networking, network-manager, pppoe, dsl

I am trying to move my PPPoE dialling from my router to two machines on that router, a Windows 7 and an Ubuntu 12.04 machine. (Actually one machine with dual boot for now).

I set up a DSL (PPPoE) connection using the Edit Connections dialogue, and while I am connected to the router via cable, the DSL connection is available and works, but as soon as I disconnect the cable, and connect to the wlan (the wifi AP is part of the router), the DSL connection is no longer visible. I need to dial the PPPoE using the wifi to connect my PC to the router. How should I do this?

My router is a a Billion 400G, set to Full Bridge. My Windows PPPoE connection works fine, cable or wifi, so the device is capable. [This video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=tNlHfM1HgHQ) - suggests I need to use pppoeconf to create the DSL connection while connected over wifi. I'll try that asap.

Comment: What's your router's model/make? It's an interesting setup you're attempting to install. I think you'll need to bridge the DSL port, but don't know if that is possible via the WiFi adapter.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously, it is at least funny question if I right understand where this intended :)
It can be missed LAN cord for example ... ok.
I suggest to clear your DSL(PPPoE) settings which you created through Edit Connections dialogue. Then reset your DSL router, and connect to him through your Ubuntu Wireless like to the default Wireless Network, by default IP. Next, just you will need configure your router through router's interface.
Defaults, like the default wireless network SSID for your router you can find at official website. However, I do not know how much possible that wireless is enabled by default.

If yes, obviously YES, it possible.